# Centering text below absolute span

Tags: html, css

In the following code, I have a div that includes a number and its units (in the example 1000 miles). The number is centered OK in the div, but I need the units to be centered right **below** the number. How is this possible?

```css
div.div1 {
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  background-color: orange;
  position: relative;
}

span.number {
  font-family: Verdana;
  font-size: 36px;
  font-weight: bold;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
}

span.units {
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="div1">
  <span class="number">1,000</span>
  <br/>
  <span class="units">miles</span>
</div>
```

Comment: Is there any special requirement for adding `position:absolute;` to your `span.number` ?

Comment: no, I just use it to center the span vertically and horizontally. If you can do that without setting absolute that works as well.

Comment: There you go: https://jsfiddle.net/vqgj2h7h/5/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just insert the text into the first span like so:

```
<div class="div1">
    <span class="number">
        1,000
        <span class="units">miles</span>
    </span>
</div>
```

And add this CSS:

```
.units{
    display:block;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 14px;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Use flexbox

```css
.div1 {
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  background-color: orange;

  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;    /* Vertical center */
  align-items: center;    /* Horizontal center */
}

.number {
  font-family: Verdana;
  font-size: 36px;
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<div class="div1">
  <span class="number">1,000</span>
  <span class="units">miles</span>
</div>
```

Comment: Up for not hard coding anything.

Answer (score 0):

One way of doing it would be using flexbox like so:

```
.div1{
  display:flex;
  flex-flow:column;
}
```

Comment: There's a little bit more that would be needed.

Answer (score 0):

Change the value of `top` in `span.units`.

```css
div.div1 {
  height:200px;
  width:200px;
  background-color:orange;
  position: relative;
}
span.number {
font-family: Verdana;
font-size: 36px;
font-weight: bold;
position: absolute;
top: 50%;
left: 50%;
transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
}
span.units {
font-family: Verdana;
font-size: 36px;
font-weight: bold;
position: absolute;
top: 70%;
left: 50%;
transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
}
```

```html
<div class="div1">
   <span class="number">1,000</span><br>
      <span class="units">miles</span>
   <br>

</div>
```

Comment: I don't think "miles" is supposed to be styled the same way as `1,000` and your code doesn't properly vertically align.

Answer (score 0):

Wrap both of them (number + units) with another div and apply the position absolute to that div.

```css
    .div1 {
      height:200px;
      width:200px;
      background-color:orange;
      position: relative;
    }
    .center {
      position: absolute;
      top: 50%;
      left: 50%;
      transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
      text-align: center;
    }
    .number {
      font-family: Verdana;
      font-size: 36px;
      font-weight: bold;
    }
```

```html
    <div class="div1">
      <div class="center">
       <span class="number">1,000</span>
       <br/>
       <span class="units">miles</span>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Best way to do this is using Flexbox, but if you don't want to do this you can add `text-align: center`, `width: 100%`, and `top: 62%` for `.units` element.

```css
div.div1 {
  height:200px;
  width:200px;
  background-color:orange;
  position: relative;
}

span.number {
  font-family: Verdana;
  font-size: 36px;
  font-weight: bold;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
}

span.units {
  margin: 0 auto;
  position: absolute;
  top: 62%;
  left: 0;
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="div1">
   <span class="number">1,000</span>
   <br/>
   <span class="units">miles</span>
</div>
```

I set a value of `top` to `62%` due to experiments. You can use another value if you think that space between value and unit is too small or too high.

Edit:

With Flexbox (as I said, it's better, because you don't use hardcoded values like that `62%`):

```css
div.div1 {
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  background-color: orange;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  flex-direction: column;
}

span.number {
  font-family: Verdana;
  font-size: 36px;
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<div class="div1">
   <span class="number">1,000</span>
   <span class="units">miles</span>
</div>
```

I also removed `<br>` tag. It's unnecessary. Use `<br>` only inside `<p>` tags.

Comment: Where did you come up with `62%`?

Comment: I came with that value by experimentation (I edited answer).

Comment: The problem with 62% is that you based it on what looked good to you, but you must remember that not everyone will be viewing the page on the same size viewport as you.

Answer (score 0):

**[CSS Flexbox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Using_CSS_flexible_boxes)** to the rescue! (and, we can get rid of a whole bunch of unneeded CSS as well)

```css
div.div1 {
    height:200px;
    width:200px;
    background-color:orange;
    display:flex;            /* Make the container a flex-container */
    justify-content:center;  /* Horizontally align children */
    align-items:center;      /* Vertically align children */
    flex-direction:column;   /* Change from row to column based layout */
}

div.number {
    font-family: Verdana;
    font-size: 36px;
    font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<div class="div1">
  <div class="number">1,000</div>
  <div class="units">miles</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The Code Snippet embedded below demonstrates the following:

1. **Standard Augmented Solution**
2. **Alternative Absolute Positioning Solution**
3. **Flex-Box Solution**

```css
div.div1 {
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  background-color: orange;
  position: relative;
}

span.number {
  font-family: Verdana;
  font-size: 36px;
  font-weight: bold;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
}

span.units {
  margin: 0 auto;
  font-family: Verdana;
  font-weight: bold;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 25%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
}


/* Additional */

.container {
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  background-color: orange;
  position: relative;
}

.container_number {
  font-family: Verdana;
  font-size: 36px;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.container_units {
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.container_inner {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  text-align: center;
  margin: auto;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  height: 30%;
}

.flex_container {
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  background-color: orange;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  text-align: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.flex_container_number {
  font-family: Verdana;
  font-size: 36px;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.flex_container_units {
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<!-- Standard Augmented Solution -->
<div class="div1">
  <span class="number">1,000</span>
  <br/>
  <span class="units">miles</span>
</div>

<hr>
<!-- Alternative Absolute Positioning Solution -->
<div class="container">
  <div class="container_inner">
    <span class="container_number">1,000</span>
    <br/>
    <span class="container_units">miles</span>
  </div>
</div>

<hr>
<!-- Flex-Box Solution -->
<div class="flex_container">
  <span class="flex_container_number">1,000</span>
  <span class="flex_container_units">miles</span>
</div>
```

**JSFiddle Demo:** https://jsfiddle.net/vqgj2h7h/5/

Answer (score 0):

Try this, Flexbox currently not supported some browser.

```css
div.div1 {
    height: 200px;
    width: 200px;
    background-color: orange;
    position: relative;
    text-align:center;
}

span.number {
    font-family: Verdana;
    padding-top: 33%;
    display: block;
    font-weight: 600;
    font-size: 36px;
}

span.units {
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="div1">
  <span class="number">1,000</span>
  <span class="units">miles</span>
</div>
```